# Vue-router doesn't remove hashbang after building for production

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I was trying to remove the hashbang and I did it by adding `mode:'history'` in the index file of vue-router:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Daksh',
      component: Daksh
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'About',
      component: About
    },
    {
      path: '/work',
      name: 'Work',
      component: Work
    }
  ]
})
```

Then It was working well when I tried it in the hot reload mode but after running `npm run build`, It stopped working for some weird reason.

Please Help :)

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: I use the build method for building the html files and then I basically use nginx to run the files. It's my portfolio site, So I didn't create a server with node.js I simply ran it with nginx.

Comment: okay where are you hosting the webapp

Comment: On my vps based on digital ocean and It doesn't matter I guess.

Comment: did you setup the server configuration for ngins as shown in example here ( https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html ).

Comment: Thanks a lot that fixed it :)

Comment: happy to help, i have seen your site , its great , and 15yrs age, you are doing great, but one small mention : being an indian i fdid'nt like what you said in the last line of 1st paragraph in the about section. That's it

Comment: Do no add [solved] to the title of your question: write an answer below, and accept your own answer: that will be a much useful indicator, and will help others.

Comment: @user7814783 I know, but that was the truth in those old times in 2006-7 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the answer has been solved within the comments and as **VonC** suggested to add an answer so that it could be helpful for others , here it is:

Sinceyou are using nginx to run the files

Setup the server configuration for nginx as shown in example in the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html)

```
location / { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; 
}
```

Comment: Now that looks helpful ;) +1

Comment: That's really helpful :)