# Symfony3 + Vuejs nginx configuration

Tags: symfony, nginx, routes, vue.js

I'm currently coding an app using SF3 for the back-end and VueJs for the front-end.

I use a controller action with the base route '/' to render the main template (with twig) containing the link to the js files and the div binding for VueJs.

The Vuejs app is a single page app and uses vue-router. The vue-router mode is set to history in production mode and that's where I am having trouble. The dev config uses the hash without any issue.

I would like to configure my nginx so that :

> 1. Checks if it matches a vuejs route
> 2. If not check that it matches a symfony route
> 3. If not then redirect to some 404 page

1 and 2 can be revert.

My current nginx location is (the default symfony one):

```
`location / {
    try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
}`
```

The issue is that when I reload a vuejs route in the browser I receive 404 errors. However, navigating route to route works fine.

If it helps, all my symfony routes are prefixed by API/ or admin/

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

---

RESOLVED

I've add a "fallback" route in my symfony configuration:

```
fallback:
  path: /{req}
  defaults: { _controller: 'AppBundle:Default:index' }
  requirements:
      req: ".+"
```

Now each undefined url is redirected to the action that renders the VueJS app. A fallback route is also defined in the vue-router in case the url does not macth a known vue-router route.

Comment: Are you using history mode in vue-router?

Comment: As I said in my message i use the history mode in production, that's where i have the issue

Comment: you need to configure your server to work with history mode.. see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43999259/vue-router-doesnt-remove-hashbang-after-building-for-production/44003157#44003157

Comment: If i get it right this supposes that index.html is the starting point of the vuejs app, which in my case is not. The  'index.html' equivalent is rendered with a symfony action using twig and the base route `/`

Comment: then serve the root HTML file where you have your vuejs script imported. I have never worked on symfony so could not completely understand how it works

Comment: @Marco, how did you get this working? I am trying the same thing but Vue does not catch dynamic route `/:dynamicparam`. So, `timetable/hello-world` - Timetable is loaded but hello-word not catched in vue-routing. Do I need to do something more?

Comment: Ok I got it, of course I had to setup route like this `{path: '/timetable/:param', component: TimetableComponent},`