# Symfony 3 routes + VueJS's index.html with F5 falls to 404

Tags: symfony, vue.js

I try connect Vue.js with Symfony 3, but have no idea how to create proper route configuration for it. 
Project tree looks like that:

```
Project root
  - app/
    - Resources/
      - views/
        - default/
  - web/
    - assets/
    - static/
    index.html     // here Vue is included
```

From Symfony I provide some REST API, the routes to it are prefixed by /api/. And I have some routes in Vue SPA. 
The problem is if I press F5 in browser on any Vue route, which of course is not included in my routing.yml, browser returns 404 error from Symfony.
One half-working decision is when I put content of index.html to Resourses/views/default/twig with such a route:

```
fallback_for_vue:
    path: /{req}
    defaults: { _controller: 'AppBundle:Default:index' }
    requirements:
        req: ".+"
```

,[taken from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45562707/symfony3-vuejs-nginx-configuration), but this is not actually what I need, because I don't want my frontend programmer to go somewhere except *web/* folder.
So which configuration of Symfony routes I should use?

Answer (score 0):

You need a wildcard address to point to your Vue.js application. Otherwise when you reload you send a request to Symfony, and it doesn't know hoy to handle it.

```
vuejs_wildcard_route:
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:YourController:yourAction }
    path:   /vuejsappbasepath/{whatever}
    requirements:
        whatever: .*
    defaults:
        whatever: null
```

I have this setup working with a reactjs app and is working perfectly.

YourController is the controller that contains yourAction, the one that loads the template with the Vue.js panel.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Carlos. Though what I want is to avoid rendering by Symfony static index.html, rendered by Vue and Webpack previously. Only return plain index.html from web/ folder, using some magic config in routing.yml. Is it possible, what you think?

Comment: If you don't want Symfony to render the twig and just serve the plain index html, you can read the file located somewhere, set it as a standard Response object body and send back to the user. I don't see any advantage against just rendering the twig file with the html and the vue,js app loaded as an standard js script.